# PHP post_max_size vs upload_max_filesize, what is the difference?

Tags: php

When trying to upload a `PDF` file that was 15mb through an admin area created for doing so, nothing happened.  There was no success or error message, but the `PDF` did not upload.

I then thought that it could be an issue with the `php.ini` settings.  Sure enough, when I looked at the file, I found that the limits were set to 8m.  Which I'm assuming means 8mb.

**post_max_size:** http://php.net/post-max-size

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
post_max_size = 20M
```

**upload_max_filesize:** http://php.net/upload-max-filesize

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Looking at the comments, it appears that one is for files being uploaded, while the other relates directly to `POST` data.  What I'm confused about is this scenario: If you have a form that is `POST`'ing an image to another page, what does that count as, `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size`?  Does it fall under both?  Does one take precedence?  Are there cases where one would be used and not the other?

**Edit:**

So if I have a form that has 3 file inputs, all allowing files 20mb or smaller, the settings would have to be set like so:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 60M
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are correct.  `post_max_size` is the maximum size for all POST body data.  It doesn't matter if you're POSTing JSON or your DVD collection, this is all POST body data.  Your file upload counts towards this limit.  You should also be aware that if you are uploading multiple files, the total file size has to fit within this limit.

`upload_max_filesize` is a maximum size only for files that are POSTed.  Other types of POST body data are not subject to this limit.

In short, if you want to upload large files, you must increase both limits.

Comment: Your webserver may also have a limit. Apache has the [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive, which could be set. If its present it has to be equal to or larger than `post_max_size`

Comment: So from what I understand if I have a form that has 3 uploads with caps at 20mb it would be fine to have `upload_max_filesize = 20M` but `post_max_size` would have to be set to `60M`?

Comment: @Brad But a post with a file is bigger than the file itself (due to mime separators, other parameters, etc) so 3 files of 20 MB each, when uploaded they will have a total size =  60MB + "some additional data coming from other parameters, mime encoding"...right?

Comment: @Alex Correct.  I should have clarified in my comment... I was trying to keep it simple.  Realistically, almost nobody is going to upload 3 files in exactly 20MB of size, so this isn't an issue.  Unless of course you have a place where that's what they do.

Answer (score 7):

`post_max_size` is like the superset. `upload_max_filesize` is in context with file uploads but `post_max_size` is checked for all kind of POST data. It can be a very big content which can be posted which is limited by `post_max_size`. So for a big file you want to upload, you need to change both the limits.

Comment: From the docs for `post_max_size`: *`"Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize."`*

Comment: @Sam I think that what Neo tried to bring attention to is that post_max_size size must contain all files but should be bigger (than the sum of all uploaded files) as it can contain much more (parameters, MIME delimiters, etc)