# How to change max upload size for files in Wordpress 4.4 at xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I wanted to upload a template to wordpress 4.4 which is running on xampp but it says that I only can upload 2MB. I've googled the problem and found an information that i need to change the parameter `upload_max_filesize=32M` in the file php.ini. I doesn't found the file in the Wordpress folder but in the xampp folder I found a file called php.ini with the parameter in it and I changed the parameter but nothing happened.

What can I do to increase the max template upload space?

Comment: Did you restart xampp after change in php.ini?

Comment: Of course I did but nothing happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this already? http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/ It contains plenty of ways to increase the max upload size.

Make sure you increase `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`, both limits.

So for example in PHP.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Cause it may take longer to upload those files, you might want to increase max_execution_time as well.
`post_max_size` is the maximum size for all POST body data. `upload_max_filesize` is a maximum size only for files that are POSTed. Other types of POST body data are not subject to this limit. See Brad's answer over here: [PHP post_max_size vs upload_max_filesize, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686505/php-post-max-size-vs-upload-max-filesize-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Ah thx. Now it works. Maybe `max_execution_time = 300` was the problem.