# difference between "upload_max_size" and "upload_max_filesize"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've found some people say about  `ini_set("upload_max_size")`,

But does `upload_max_size` exist at all, and is it something new? As I know  `upload_max_filesize` is the correct syntax. Am I wrong?

Comment: yeah that doesn't exist - might be referring to `post_max_size` - see here for difference between that and `upload_max_filesize`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686505/php-post-max-size-vs-upload-max-filesize-what-is-the-difference

Comment: That could be post_max_size

Comment: It's [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), not `upload_max_size`

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)?

Comment: If you didn't find it on Google or the php.net website, then it doesn't exist. *"but does upload_max_size exist at all? Is it something new?"* - No.

Comment: [*"upload_max_size doesn't exist. Closest matches:"*](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=upload_max_size&scope=quickref)

Comment: *"But does upload_max_size exist at all, and is it something new?"* - I'm wondering why you even asked that. IMHO, the question's unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i  your answer is good point. post it as answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but the loyal question why you dont understand, is not appealing for me. because people like you (see another answer in this topic) say that it exists. and why u are surprised, that i become confused? Am I alien?

Comment: @T.Todua I posted my answer but as a community wiki. I didn't want to pass off as being nasty here. I figured that you could have Google'd this or search the php.net website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `ini_set("upload_max_size")` function exist in wordpress. for example:

`@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );` using in `functions.php` file link is [HERE](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/)

In `php.ini` -> `upload_max_filesize` is using.

Finally `htaccess` syntax is `php_value upload_max_filesize`

Comment: But is this having any effect? It seems like a bug in Wordpress, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this as a community wiki since it was raised in comments.

As per my comments:

> *"If you didn't find it on Google or the php.net website, then it doesn't exist. "but does upload_max_size exist at all? Is it something new?" - No"*.

and a link for a search on the php.net website:

> [*"http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=upload_max_size&scope=quickref"*](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=upload_max_size&scope=quickref)