# Wordpress file size limit 2MB, linux host .. none of solutions online working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling to increase Maximum upload file size: 2 MB on my linux machine where I host my wordpress website... Things I tried and that are still active:

.htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

editing wordpress theme functions.php

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

wp-settings.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
define('WP_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE' , '64M');
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '64M' );
```

adding php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

and doing service apache2 restart(even stop and start...) so it's not the restart because I saw one linux thread with this subject and his solution at the end was:

> The problem was that I had to restart the apache server in a different way I guess

These are all the fixes I could find online and I became pretty desperate being stuck on this problem for so long ... Hopefully someone will help!

Comment: What error do you get when you try to upload a file?

Comment: Also there is a difference in your settings, you are talking about `upload_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712556/difference-between-upload-max-size-and-upload-max-filesize) for the difference, and how to correct it.

Comment: @TomWalters .gif exceeds the maximum upload size for this site. And div above says : Maximum upload file size: 2 MB.

Comment: @Luuk Yes I understand the difference now, but still i'm trying to increase maximum upload file size which I have in php.ini and in wp-confing.php ... aslo in .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to overcome this error...
The solution was to edit the php.ini located at

```
/etc/php/7.3/apache2
```

if even that doesn't work for you, try editing php.ini at these locations as well:

```
/etc/php/7.3/cli

/etc/php/7.3/cgi
```

adding this line

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

and maybe this too

```
post_max_size 64M
```

conclusion.. if you have your own linux server you will have to change the apache2 default php.ini settings because even if you setup the new php.ini at wordpress files location, the one in apache2 folder is apsolute so firstly you need to increase upload_max_filesize there.

Comment: This was also mentioned earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724511/how-to-check-where-apache-is-looking-for-a-php-ini-file

Comment: @Luuk yea, well some php expert would solve this in 2mins but I'm not good at debugging or checking the configuration of php so it took me a while..
Also I read this on some article that it's possible there are more then 1 php.ini so I looked for them... It's not like I found the issue myself xD

Comment: My reaction was mainly for future readers of this, to get more info on this. Besides that, iy is good that you found the solution to your own problem...