# .zip file upload tool aravel Laravel 5.6 Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException

Tags: php, upload, laravel-5.6

I am getting this error when upload a file that is 191.1MB

> Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException

I do have my nginx set to 1000M and PHP.INI set to 1000M on the upload limits and i am getting no errors from them. But Laravel 5.6 is giving me the error:

[image]

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: What about POST_MAX_SIZE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP post\_max\_size vs upload\_max\_filesize, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686505/php-post-max-size-vs-upload-max-filesize-what-is-the-difference)