# Laravel 5.8 multi-upload inputs

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I want to be able to upload multiple (dynamic) files (pdf).

So I have the following lay-out:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/TLk3dvv.png]

As you can see, the form has 4 input fields for files, but it also has 2 text fields and for every file upload row, it has a checkbox. The "flow" is the following:

1. Add title and year
2. Check the classes (Initiatie, Recreatie, Toersime, and Sport) you want to enable (and upload a PDF for)
3. Upload 1 PDF file per class.

The files are PDF files (1 per class). I tried the following code in PHP to upload the files, but I can only upload one, sometimes 2 files at a time, depending on how large the files are.

```
public function postGapersritAddResults(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    // Handle upload
    $path = 'documents/gapersrit/'.$request->get('year').'/results';

    foreach (['initiatie', 'recreatie', 'toerisme', 'sport'] as $item) {
        if ($request->hasFile('file_'.$item)) {
            $request->file('file_'.$item)->storeAs($path, $item.'.'.$request->file('file_'.$item)->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'webdav');
        }
    }

    // Handle database
    $result = new SiteGapersritResults();
    $result->title = $request->get('title');
    $result->year = $request->get('year');
    $result->initiatie =  filter_var($request->get('active_initiatie'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    $result->recreatie =  filter_var($request->get('active_recreatie'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    $result->toerisme =  filter_var($request->get('active_toerisme'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    $result->sport =  filter_var($request->get('active_sport'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    $result->save();

    toastr()->success('Saved the results for year '.$result->year.'.', 'Success', ['timeOut' => 5000]);
    return redirect()->to('admin/gapersrit/results');
}
```

If someone has a better idea of how I could do this, please help me out.
Ideally, I want to select all the files and be able to upload them one by one (like in my code), but for some reason, this doesn't work and throws most of the time the too large error, however, I guess I'm uploading one file at a time?

**Edit**
The limit for upload sizes is 100M in php.ini and my Nginx configuration.

**Edit 2**
I get the following error on my current code:

`curl_exec(): CURLOPT_INFILE resource has gone away, resetting to default`

full trace: https://pastebin.com/rqUeEhGa

Comment: Are you checking for errors???

Comment: ___too large error___ PLEASE always show us ALL the error message(s) Dont summarise them as all there content is useful

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the upload size is limited by the `php.ini` config of your server.

If you have access to the file or the php settings, try changing these values:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

**Edit** also see see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23686617/7584725

Comment: The limit for upload sizes is 100M, Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Ok, but how large are the files that you are uploding when it fails

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the error is `curl_exec(): CURLOPT_INFILE resource has gone away, resetting to default`

The code snippet you posted does not contain anything related to `curl`, the problem is the "webdav" disk in the `saveAs` function.

Looking at the trace, this seems like there is a problem in the `League\Flysystem\WebDAV\` package, maybe

https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-webdav/issues/49  or
https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-webdav/issues/50

Comment: I use the `storeAs()` function here, but I have no clue what's wrong about my code

Comment: If you read my answer correctly then you would have noticed that there is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. the problem is in the `League\Flysystem\WebDAV\` package