# howto setup maxFileSize in Typo3 9.5.8

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, upload-max-filesize

i set up my php.ini  to upload_max_filesize=12M, that works fine in phpinfo();

But typo3 9.5.8 still doesn't accept files to upload larger than 8mb.

And there is no more option to find in Typosettings like ['BE']['maxFileSize'] where i am able to change these settings.

What's the way to change it?

Comment: Did you also increase `post_max_size`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686505/

Comment: thanks, such simple i didn't check this because i thougt file upload doesnt belong to POST

Comment: I've posted a proper answer now, you can accept it if you like. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to `upload_max_filesize` you also need to increase `post_max_size` which contains all POSTed data. See [PHP post_max_size vs upload_max_filesize, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686505/) for details.